# Mysql GROUP BY optimization with inner joins and large dataset

Tags: mysql, database

Hi I have a product category database where products and categories have a many to many relationship using a third table eg. product_category. Now, Im running a query on the database in order to fetch all products that belongs to a category given on an array of category ids, lets see the following example:

```
SELECT * FROM products p JOIN product_category pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
WHERE pc.category_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) GROUP BY p.id LIMIT 0,40
```

The products table haves around 23k rows and the product_category table 26k rows.

Usually the array of category ids used in the WHERE IN clause has much more elements.

Now this query takes **300ms** to fetch the results. If I remove the GROUP BY clause then the query only takes **2ms** to fetch the results.

A more complete query is as follows:

```
select * from `products` inner join `product_category` on `products`.`id` = `product_category`.`product_id`
        where `product_category`.`category_id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 
    '8', '44', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '160', '161', '162', '168', '169', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', 
    '178', '179', '180', '181', '182', '183', '184', '185', '186', '189', '190', '191', '192', '193', '194', '195', '196',
     '197', '198', '199', '200', '201', '202', '203', '204', '205', '206', '207', '208', '209', '213', '215', '216', '217', 
    '218', '219', '230', '231', '232', '233', 
    '234', '235', '236', '237', '240', '241', 
    '242', '243', '244', '245', '246', '247', 
    '248', '249', '250', '251', '252', '253', 
    '254', '255', '256', '257', '258', '259', 
    '260', '261', '325', '326', '327', '328', 
    '334', '335', '336', '337', '338', '339', '340', '341', '342', '343', '344') and `products`.`is_visible` = '1' 
    group by `product_category`.`product_id` 
    order by `popularity` desc, `popularity` desc limit 40 offset 0
```

The explain of the query is as follows:

[image: Explain of the query]

So, my question is if there is a way to optimize the query specifically the group by so it does not take too long lo load the results.

Comment: Since you are not aggregating, have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT p.*`  instead?

Comment: @Uueerdo Yes I have, with no change, the query with Select Distinct takes more or less the same time that with the group by. Thanks

Comment: Yo should never use that group by structure as it is not guaranteed to always give the same results in the fields that you did not specify in the group by. Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.Use group by properly the way every other database requires. Also never use SELECT * when you have a  join as it returns more data than you need (the join fields are repeated) and that contributes to the slowness of the query. Both of these syntax issues are SQL Antipatterns and you would flunk code review if you tried to pass it by someone who actually understands databases.

Comment: @HLGEM Thanks for the given suggestions, the * in the select is used for brevity. Can you give a response to my question as a database expert?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, you might have some luck with `SELECT DISTINCT p.*`; but I usually see people using `GROUP BY` to get around `DISTINCT` slowness...

Another option is to use a subquery instead of a direct JOIN, like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products` 
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT `product_id` 
   FROM `product_category` 
   WHERE `category_id` IN ([category id list])
) 
AND `is_visible` = '1' 
ORDER BY `popularity` DESC, `popularity` DESC
LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0
```

or

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM `products` AS p
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT `product_id` 
   FROM `product_category` 
   WHERE `category_id` IN ([category id list])
) AS pcSmry ON p.id = pcSmry.product_id
WHERE p.`is_visible` = '1' 
ORDER BY `popularity` DESC, `popularity` DESC
LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0
```

---

EDIT: If neither of those help, you probably want to look into indexing the fields used in `WHERE` and `ON` conditions.